# Firefox is using Times New Roman for its UI

Tags: windows-8, firefox

For some reason, Firefox decides to use Times New Roman for its UI:
[image]

Not only the menu, but *everything* (except the webpage itself):
[image]

and
[image]

---

So how do I change it back to its original font, if possible? Times New Roman is hurting my eyes. I'm using Firefox 36 on Windows 8.

---

Edit:
[image]
I've tried changing it to the font I wanted, restarted, but it's still showing up as Times. Strangely, if I change it to Arial, it does work.

Comment: Options -> Content -> Select a Font.  This isn't really worthy of an answer since you easily could have checked if there was an option to change the font.

Comment: @Ramhound Well I've changed that already (before asking on here), but it's still using Times.

Comment: You changed it then restarted the browser?  The default font for the UI is suppose to be Times New Roman.  You might want to mention you tried changing the font within the interface without success.  I personally had no problems changing it.

Comment: @Ramhound - Added that to the question.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue a while back, and it turned out the font I was attempting to use somehow got corrupted. Are you sure the LiHei Pro font (or whatever font you want to use) is correctly installed (i.e. can it be used by other programs, or is Firefox the only one having problems)? That it works fine with Arial seems to indicate that this is the problem.

My suggestion is to reinstall the font and see if that fixes the problem.

Comment: It should be installed correctly since it's applied system-wide (by modifying various registries...) and it is working quite fine.